# C++ Time class has no compilation error, execution stops and app crashes error in checkDay function

Tags: c++

below is the date.h , date. cpp and main.cpp
i do not get any compilation error. but the run of exe stops , this does not happen when checkday function of date class is removed. what is wrong with the function? i am using dev C++

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

class Date{
  private: 
           int day, month, year;
  public:
           Date(int = 1, int = 1, int = 1990);
           ~Date();
           void setDay(int);
           int checkDay(int); //return int i.e. default day 1 or correct date inputted :)
           void setMonth(int);
           void setYear(int);
           int getDay() const;
           int getMonth() const;
           int getYear() const;
           void printDate() const;
};

#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#include "date.h"

Date::Date(int d, int m, int y){

           //setDay(d); calling setDay() here caused crash
           setMonth(m);
           setYear(y);
           setDay(d);
}
 Date::~Date(){

          cout<<"Date destructor called...\n";
}
void Date::setDay(int d){

          day = checkDay ( d ) ;
}
int Date::checkDay(int dd){ /*COMMENTING THIS FUNCTION REMOVES RUN TIME   ERROR */

          static int daysInmonth[13] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
          if ( dd > 0 && dd <= daysInmonth[month] )
             return dd;
          if( ( year%400==0||( year%100!=0 && year%4==0))&& month==2 && dd==29) 
             return dd;               
          return 1;        
}

void Date::setMonth(int m){

          month = ((m > 0 && m <=12) ? m : 1 );
}
void Date::setYear(int y){

          if (((int)log10((double)y) + 1)!=4) //ild1 != 4
             year = 1990;
          else year = y;
}
int Date::getDay() const{

          return day;
}
int Date::getMonth() const{

          return month;
}
int Date::getYear() const{

          return year;
} 

void Date::printDate() const{

          cout<<"Date: "<<getDay()<<"/"<<getMonth()<<"/"<<getYear()<<endl;
}



#include <cstdlib>    
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Date date1( 2, 3, 2004),date2,date3( 2, 1, -1980), 
      date4(0, 12, 2990),date5(29, 2, 2001), date6(12,12, 98686);

cout<<"User inputted valid date: "; date1.printDate();
cout<<"\nDefault valid date: "; date2.printDate();
cout<<"\nAttempt to input invalid date: 2/1/-1980 "; date3.printDate();
cout<<"\nAttempt to input invalid date: 0/12/2990 "; date4.printDate();
cout<<"\nAttempt to input invalid date: 29/2/2001 ( non leap year) "; date5.printDate();   
cout<<"\nAttempt to input invalid date: 12/12/98686 "; date6.printDate();  

cout<<endl;
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: did you try... ummm... debugging?

Answer (score 2):

In checkDay() you do your checks for the day considering the month and year but in the Date constructor you start with the day first when month and year are not yet assigned.

Change this:

```
Date::Date(int d, int m, int y){

       setDay(d);
       setMonth(m);
       setYear(y);
}
```

to this:

```
Date::Date(int d, int m, int y){       
       setMonth(m);
       setYear(y);
       setDay(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only point I see where the `checkDay()` method can crash, is if access to `daysInmonth[month]` is out of bounds.

Did you check what's the value of `month` when the first `if` statement is executed?